# Lagrangian method for a silmple linear programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to solve a simple LP using Lagrangian method. But I don't know how to use the soloution of the dual problem to find the solution of the main LP.

I consider the following simple problem:
$$ \min_{x} \sum_{i=1}^n -f_ix_i $$
$$ \text{s.t.}\quad  \sum_{i=0}^n x_i=1, x\ge 0 $$

The general form is:
$$ \min c^Tx $$
$$ \text{s.t.}\quad  Ax=b, x\ge 0 $$

In my problem: $A=[1 \, 1\,1 \cdots \,1]$,
$c=-f=[-f_1\,-f_2\,\cdots\,-f_n]^T$ and $b=1$.

The dual problem [will be](https://www.princeton.edu/~chiangm/ele539l3a.pdf):
$$\max \,-v$$
$$\text{s.t. }A^Tv-f\ge 0$$

The constraint means:
$$\forall i\le n, \, v\ge f_i\Rightarrow -v\le -f_i$$
$$\Rightarrow -v\le \min{-f_i} \Rightarrow \,-v= \min{-f_i}= -\max f_i\Rightarrow v=\max f_i$$

Therefore I've solved the dual problem. but what is the solution of the original problem? My question is:

> In general how can I find the solution $x$ after solving the dual problem for $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Complementary Slackness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Complementary_slackness) tells us that either the inequality $i$ in $A^Tv_{opt}-f\ge 0$ becomes *equality* or $x_i=0$. Assuming all the numbers $f_i$ are distinct and $\nu_{opt}=\max f_i=f_k$. Then $\nu_{opt}>f_i$ for $i\ne k$, hence, $x_i=0$ for $i\ne k$. Clearly then $x_k=1$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it similar to KKT? I didn't understand the descriptions of Wikipedia for complementary slackness.

Comment: @SMA.D It is a part of KKT. For inequalities $g(x)\le 0$ the Lagrange function is $f(x)+u^Tg(x)$, then in KKT there is a condition that $u_i g_i(x)=0$. It is CSP.